# circuitikz: How to add + , - in ammeter?

Tags: circuitikz

**I created Ammeter with out arrow. I want to add + and - outside the ammeter.**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{circuitikz}[x=3cm,y=3cm]
\draw (0,0) to[ammeter] ++(1,0);
\draw (0,-1) to node[draw,circle,fill=white,thick]{A} ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: the standard ammeter symbol, per IEC 60617, should _not_ have any arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{circuitikz}[x=3cm,y=3cm]
\draw (0,0) to[ammeter] ++(1,0);
\draw (0,-1) to node[draw,circle,fill=white,thick](A){A} ++(1,0);
\node[xshift=-3mm] at (A.south west){$+$};
\node[xshift=3mm] at (A.south east){$-$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could do it manually by placing some nodes right next to it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{circuitikz}[x=3cm,y=3cm]
\draw (0,0) to[ammeter] ++(1,0);
\draw (0,-1) to node[draw,circle,fill=white,thick](a){A} ++(1,0);
\path (a.west) node[above left,inner sep=1pt] {$-$} (a.east) node[above
right,inner sep=1pt] {$+$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]